# Extjs Displayfield is not getting populated from the store

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs

I am new to Ext JS and now a little stuck on something that appears to be easy but I dont know how to go about achieving it.

I am trying to retrieve the data from the store that should appear in `field.displayfield` format but I am not able to do so.

Example:
Name: Machine 45

Machine 45 should be retrieved from the store procedure but when i define:

```
store:abc,
value: 'program_id'
```

Instead of displaying the value under the `program_id` column it displays `'program_id'`, i.e

```
Name:  program_id.
```

Any idea how i can link the store procedure and `Ext.form.field.Display`? I have tried every possible suggestion I found online.

My code in the view file is:

```
var name = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Display', {
    xtype: 'displayfield',
    id: 'program_name',
    name: 'name',
    fieldLabel: 'Name',
    labelWidth: '250px',
    width: 450,
    height: 20,
    store: programAssetArray,
    value: 'o_program_id'
});

me.items.push(name);
```

And the store code is:

```
Ext.define('Availability.store.ProgramData', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.ArrayStore',
    fields: [
        {name: 'o_program_id', type: 'integer'},
        {name: 'o_program_name', type: 'text'},
        {name: 'o_parts_expected', type: 'integer'},
        {name: 'o_start_time', type: 'bigint'},
        {name: 'o_end_time', type: 'bigint'},
        {name: 'o_duration', type: 'bigint'},
        {name: 'o_station_id', type: 'integer'},
        {name: 'o_head_id', type:'integer'}
    ]
});
```

So, how can i retrieve the data from the store procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Display field can display only one value - you cannot declare a store to it. You need display fields to all of your store values. They should be combined in a [Form](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel) and you can load a record from the store in your form.

Your `name` property should be `o_program_id` and the value shouldn't be hardcoded:

```
var name = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Display', {
    //  ...
    name: 'o_program_id',
    // ...
});
```

And you can declare such fields for each of your record values.

Comment: Thanks Darin.
I am still a little confused. o_program_id is the column name whose values I am trying to retrieve in the displayField. If name:'o_program_id', then what should be ' value:??'.

Comment: Value comes from the record of the Store. You can load the record with the method `loadRecord()` of the form.